# Php save variable (globally?) from local

Tags: php

I should really know this by now, but I just can't figure it out anyway. Really weird because I thought I knew it but I just can't get it to work anyway. Well I have this code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['item_id'])){
        $item_number = $_POST['item_id'];
        require('../includes/db_connect.php');

        /* Register a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT rotation FROM house_room1 WHERE ref_id = ?')) {
            /* Bind parametres */
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_number);

            /* Execute the query */
            $stmt->execute();                   
            $stmt->bind_result($rotation);  
            while ($stmt->fetch()) { }

            /* Close statement */
            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            /* Something went wrong */
            echo 'Something went terribly wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
        }

        /* Register a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET rotation = ? WHERE ref_id = ?')) {

            /* Bind parametres */
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $i, $item_number);              
            $i = ($rotation + 1) % 5);

            /* Execute the query */
            $stmt->execute();

            /* Close statement */
            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            /* Something went wrong */
            echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have this variable `rotation` which I get out from the database in the first `SELECT` statement. I need this value in the next query, `UPDATE` but the rotation variable is local I guess? So I can't reach it in the next query, how would I do this most effeciently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: " echo 'Something went terribly wrong' "

Comment: What makes you think so? Did you try outputting `var_dump($rotation);`?

Comment: I think every fetch re-fills the bind parameter with a new value, including the last fetch, which ends the while loop. I think that last one might flush the variable and reset it to `null` or something, because there is no more data. But to be certain, just dump (or otherwise inspect) the variable and see what it contains, as @AmalMurali suggests.

Comment: You don't need the `while ($stmt->fetch()) {}` for single result row you can just call `$stmt->fetch();`. You also have a loose `)` at `$i = ($rotation + 1) % 5);` and I am not entirely sure but I think you could resume your query with `UPDATE house_room1 SET rotation = ((rotation + 1) % 5) WHERE ref_id = ?`

Comment: @Prix lol that was what caused the error^, I needed a ( .. Wauw.. Thanks a lot. Btw guys, when I write var_dump($rotation); where can I expect the result to be shown? Like it doesn't say anywhere what the value or type of $rotation is.

Comment: @owwyess check my comment again, you don't even need to make 2 queries.

Comment: Wouldn't it make the most sense to just say `UPDATE house_room1 SET rotation = (rotation + 1) % 5 WHERE id = ?;`?

Comment: Oh yeah good idea, thanks a lot, that saved me a lot of code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `$rotation` as `$rotation=null;` after `require` statement. This way it will be available on the second query.